# On the way of solving lim$_{x\rightarrow0}\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\frac{\cos t^{2}}{xsinx}dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> **Question** lim$_{x\rightarrow0}\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\frac{\cos(t^{2})}{x \sin x}dx$

**My Approach** 
$$I=\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\frac{\cos(t^2)}{x \sin x}dx$$

$$\frac{dI}{dx}=2x\cdot \frac{\cos(x^4)}{x\sin x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{dI}{dx}=2\cdot \frac{\cos(x^4)}{x\frac{\sin x}{x}}=\frac{2}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(I=2\log x) =-\infty$$

Book says answer is 1

**Note**I know my method is very much wrong.but i dont know anything
else than this.If i do not add my approach.My question will be declared
off-topic

Comment: This is vague with $t$ and $x$. Is that $dt$ instead of $dx$.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\cos(t^2)\,dt}{x\sin x}\stackrel{t\mapsto u^2}{=} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x}2u\cos(u^4)\,du}{x\sin x}\stackrel{d.H.}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\cos(x^4)}{\sin x+x\cos x}$$
by applying de l'Hopital's rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus.
The last limit equals
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\cos(x^4)}{\frac{\sin x}{x}+\cos x} = \frac{2}{1+1} =\color{red}{1}.$$
You have to be careful because
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2} f(t)\,dt \color{red}{\neq} f(x^2).$$
By the chain rule the LHS is actually $2x\,f(x^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the limit of
$$\frac1{x\sin x}\int_0^{x^2}\cos t^2\,dt.$$
For $t$ near zero, $\cos t^2=1+O(t^4)$, so
$$\int_0^{x^2}\cos t^2\,dt=\int_0^{x^2}(1+O(t^4))\,dt=x^2+O(x^{10}).$$
On the other hand, $x\sin x=x^2+O(x^4)$ and so the limit is
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+O(x^{10})}{x^2+O(x^4)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+O(x^8)}{1+O(x^2)}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Write 
\begin{align*}
\cos u=1-\dfrac{u^{2}}{2!}+\cdots,
\end{align*}
then 
\begin{align*}
\cos t^{2}=1-\dfrac{t^{4}}{2!}+\cdots,
\end{align*}
raising to the integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x^{2}}$ gets $x^{2}-\dfrac{x^{10}}{5\cdot 2!}+\cdots$, so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\cos t^{2}dt}{x\sin x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{x^{2}-\dfrac{x^{10}}{5\cdot 2!}+\cdots}{x\sin x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\dfrac{x}{\sin x}-\dfrac{x}{\sin x}\dfrac{x^{8}}{5\cdot 2!}+\cdots\right)=1.
\end{align*}